# How to upload image to web folder codeigniter 3.0

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I have working this too long, looking everywhere can't fix this, I need to upload image to a folder in web.
Please  help me show the working code model, controller and view, I want to upload the image to `"./assets/images"`, Here's my folder, 
`RootFolder->assets->images`, When I run it is echo success but the image not upload to the folder
the code :

**View :**

```
    <div class="badanAdmin">
        <div id="subMenuAdmin">

            </div>
            <div id="contentAdmin">


                    <?php 
                        echo form_open_multipart("adminFolder/adminUpload/doUpload");

                        echo form_upload("userfile");

                        echo form_submit("input_picture", "Input now !!!");

                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**controller :**

```
public function doUpload(){

        $path = "./assets/images";
        chmod($path, 0777);
        $config["upload_path"] = $path;
        $config["allowed_types"] = "jpg|png|jpeg";
        $config["max_size"] = "6000";
        $config["max_height"] = "7680";
        $config["max_width"] = "10240";

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);
        //$this->upload->do_upload("userfile");

        if( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
            //$error = array("error" => $this->upload->display_errors());

            //$this->load->view();

            echo "failed";
        }else{
            //$data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());

            //redirect("admin/picture", $data);

            echo "success";
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you show use your code

Comment: Can you post the code you are using, both in the controller and in the view.  Are you setting the form to be a multipart form, and are you using the right field name when processing the upload?

Comment: submit your full code

Comment: here's my code, please help

Comment: $path = "./assets/images"; check your path and give the actual path from root folder

Comment: @saty CodeIgniter allows you to use ./ at the start of the path and then uses it to work from the root of CodeIgniter, so it doesn't need to be the full or actual path

Comment: @raymondspark you're running a check for !$this->upload->do_upload(), so it will show your "succses" when it fails

Comment: change yore path to  $path = "./assets/images/";

Comment: change yore path to $path = "./assets/images/"; doesn't work either. i don't know what to do anymore. it's all seems right, i've flip the echo statement

Comment: print_r($_FILES) in your doUpload function and check

Comment: it's done. it is because i am autoload the library "upload", when i erase the autoload "upload", its worked perfectly, thank you all for the help !!!

Comment: One suggestion.Use `$path = FCPATH."assets/images";`

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code you have, it's difficult to answer.  I've got a few common problems that people have when using CodeIgniter which you might want to try:

1) Make sure the folder you are trying to upload to is able to be written to by the web server
2) Make sure the view has a for which is multipart (use the following code:)

```
echo form_open_multipart('/path/to/processing/page');
```

3) Ensure that the upload config has the location set to upload the files to (using the following:)

```
 $config['upload_path']          = './path/to/upload/to/';
```

4) Ensure that when you run do_upload(), you have the right field name set.

5) Check your php.ini for max_upload_size and ensure that it's large enough to cover the size of the file you are uploading.  This is usually defaulted to 2Mb

CodeIgniter documentation is pretty good in this respect, so check out http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=file%20upload